# How to override function in extensions for inherited classes?

Tags: swift, extension-methods

I have a `scrollToBottom` function for `UIScrollView` and `UITableView`. The problem is they are conflicting with each other with the error: `Declarations in extensions cannot override yet`

This is what I have:

```
extension UIScrollView {

    func scrollToBottom(animated: Bool = true) {
        ...
    }
}

extension UITableView {

    func scrollToBottom(animated: Bool = true) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Since `UITableView` inherits from `UIScrollView`, it's not allowing me to do this. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a protocol `ScrollableToBottom` and define your method there:

```
protocol ScrollableToBottom {
    func scrollToBottom(animated: Bool)
}
```

Make `UIScrollView` and `UITableView` inherit from it:

```
extension UIScrollView: ScrollableToBottom  { }
extension UITableView: ScrollableToBottom  { }
```

Then you just need to extend your protocol constraining `Self` to the specific class:

```
extension ScrollableToBottom where Self: UIScrollView {
    func scrollToBottom(animated: Bool = true) {

    }
}
extension ScrollableToBottom where Self: UITableView {
    func scrollToBottom(animated: Bool = true) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Clear and elegant way to go and works! BTW the redundant tableview protocol conformance isn't needed. Thx!

Comment: Yes but this would be required if you need to implement this method also in CollectionView

Answer (score 1):

You can use protocol extension with default implementation

```
protocol CanScrollBottom {
    func scrollToBottom()
}

extension CanScrollBottom where Self: UIScrollView {
    func scrollToBottom() {
        //default implementation
    }
}

extension UIScrollView: CanScrollBottom { }

extension UITableView {
    func scrollToBottom() {
        //override default implementation
    }
}
```